# Inefficient Java program when using date

Tags: java, date, time, jframe

My program seem to be using 20% of the CPU and around 1GB of RAM. I think its because I am looping the date. I am trying to make a clock appear on my JFrame (hours, mins and seconds always updating). My question is, how can I make my program less hungry for power?
Here's my code:

```
while(true){
    Date date = new Date();
    time.setText(date.getHours() + " hours " + date.getMinutes() 
                 + " minutes " + date.getSeconds() + " seconds!");
}
```

Comment: Remove the infinite loop which never breaks !

Comment: As the previous comment states, it's an infinite loop.
What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think part of the problem is `String` concatenation. Might want to rethink the way you set the text. You can also declare your `Date` outside the loop, less garbage collecting.

Comment: No you do not need an infinite loop. An infinite loop updates your clock every cycle the loop does (thousands in a second). You should update your clock **only once every second**. See other peoples answers below on how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't loop. Whatever the application, the above infinite loop will place a constant demand on resources.

In this case, it appears you are using Swing. This is even worse for `Swing` applications. Infinite loops prevent UI updates.

Use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead and set an period interval large enough that will allow updates to be observed and will demand less overhead from the CPU. `1000` milliseconds should do.

```
public class TimerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Timer Demo");
                final JLabel timeLabel = 
                             new JLabel("-----------------------------------------------");
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH' hours 'mm' minutes 'ss' seconds'");
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Date date = new Date();
                        timeLabel.setText(format.format(date));
                    }
                });

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(timeLabel);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.pack();
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "*Infinite loops prevent UI updates.*" I guess OP started a new thread. Otherwise OP will notice that UI is not responding instead of the 20% CPU usage, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid this, use [**SwingTimer**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), swing timer not need any loop.

Here a full example:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class DateAndTimer extends JFrame {
 private javax.swing.Timer timer;
 private JLabel label ;
 private Date ;
 public DateAndTimer(){
  this.timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000,getActionTimer());
  date = new Date();
  label = new JLabel();
  add(label,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  timer.start();
  setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
  setVisible(true);
  pack();

 }

 public ActionListener getActionTimer(){
  ActionListener action = new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

      label.setText(date.getHours() + " hours " + date.getMinutes()
                 + " minutes " + date.getSeconds() + " seconds!");
 }
 };
 return action;
}

public static void main(String...args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
           new DateAndTimer();
    }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

How can I make my program less hungry for power? Make your thread sleep for a while. <sub>I assumed the code @Cj1m given is run in a newly started thread.</sub>

See [`java.lang.Thread.sleep(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

```
while(true){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ // make sure to run in EDT
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Date date = new Date();
            time.setText(date.getHours() + " hours " + date.getMinutes() 
                    + " minutes " + date.getSeconds() + " seconds!");
        }
    });
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds.
                            // Give a shorter interval if you like.
    } catch(InterruptedException e) { // Who interrupted my dream?
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or use Swing Timer as others described.

Comment: I don't do `Thread#sleep()`, If you sleep the EDT your entire GUI will hang and become unresponsive until the thread wakes up. This is bad.

Comment: Suppose I want press start button to start counting the time, after pressing the button, the frame will freezes until the loop stops.

Comment: I know that, so, why you give an advice to use infinity loop? I know he did, but he is wrong.

Comment: @Azad I know he used infinity loop, and I assumed that he did not suffer from the block of EDT. So I assumed the code OP given is run in a newly started thread.

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop with tiny load (setting date) would obviously take huge CPU, introducing `sleep` will lessen CPU usage:

```
while(true){
    Date date = new Date();
    time.setText(date.getHours() + " hours " + date.getMinutes() 
                 + " minutes " + date.getSeconds() + " seconds!");
    Thread.sleep(1000);//1second update of clock
}
```

Comment: Thread.sleep doesn't work on its own, Do i need to at try/catch to it?

Comment: Yes, you do, since it `throws InterruptedException` which is checked. It's upto you where do you want to `catch` it, inside or outside `while` loop as to abort loop or not..