# Continuously check the time?

Tags: java, swing

So I'm making a little sample application that displays train times.
Right now the `JTable` in which the trains are displayed isn't dynamic.
What I'd like, is for the time to be checked every `30 secs or minute` and the table would eliminate a train that "should have arrived".
I'm stuck however at the constantly checking time part. I've created a `TimeChecker` class to run in the background but it's not much use as when I put a infinite loop or thread into my `JPanel` class, the user interface doesn't show.

Here's my TimeChecker:

```
package controller;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TimeChecker extends Thread {
    private String timeStamp;

    public String getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                String dateStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(
                                Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                timeStamp = dateStamp.substring(9,13);
                System.out.println(timeStamp);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my Panel class:

```
package view;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import controller.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel {
    /* JPanel containing the JTabbedPane stuff */
    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    TimeChecker tc = new TimeChecker();

    public Panel() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));
        Table t = new Table("Haymarket");
        jtp.add(t);
        jtp.setTitleAt(0, "Haymarket");
        add(jtp);
        tc.setDaemon(true);
        tc.start();
    }

    public void addTrain(String d, String c, String dep, String a) {
        /* 
         * Receives 4 parameters to control 
         * the new entry required for a train 
         */
        Table t = (Table) jtp.getComponentAt(jtp.getSelectedIndex());
        t.addTrain(d,c,dep,a);
    }

    public void addStation(String s) {
        /* 
         * Adds a station, after prompting the 
         * user for a station name 
         */
        jtp.add(new Table(s));
        jtp.setTitleAt(jtp.getTabCount()-1, s);
        jtp.setSelectedIndex(jtp.getTabCount()-1);
    }

    public void addStation(Table t) {
        jtp.add(t);
        jtp.setTitleAt(jtp.getTabCount()-1,t.getStation());
    }

    public void removeAllStations() {
        jtp.removeAll();
    }

    public void removeStation() {
        /* 
         * Removes currently selected station 
         */
        jtp.remove(jtp.getSelectedIndex());
    }

    public void removeTrain() {
        /* 
         * WIP: Removes a train 
         */
        Table t = (Table) jtp.getComponentAt(jtp.getSelectedIndex());
        t.removeTrain();
    }
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop, you don't need that, use [**Swing Timer**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead, see [this example, maybe helps you in some how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923299/inefficient-java-program-when-using-date/17923358#17923358)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to fire every 30 seconds.

Alternatively, use a timer in a background thread (e.g. via a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)) - then fetch the information and only get the UI involved when you actually need to update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a thread from the UI, which means that the thread will run with the same priority as the UI. You should not do that, but use [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) instead.